# How to get repeated item's values with ng-options on ng-change? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have cars object and I'm binding it on my selectbox. I want to get all values of my selectbox repeated options. I am trying to get my selected car's value with passing a parameter by function. How should I do this?

My codes below.

Thank you!

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);


app.controller("Controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.val = "";


  $scope.cars = [{
    "no": "1",
    "name": "Audi"
  }, {
    "no": "2",
    "name": "Opel"
  }, {
    "no": "3",
    "name": "Volkwagen"
  }, {
    "no": "4",
    "name": "Skoda"
  }, {
    "no": "5",
    "name": "Mercedes"
  }];

  $scope.Do = function(resp) {
    $scope.val = "current car's val is: " + resp;
  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Controller">

  <select ng-model="araba" ng-options="item.name for item in cars" ng-change="Do(item.no)"></select>

  <p>{{val}}</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try passing complete object to the function `Do(item)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many peoples asking same question in here, we can get a selected value from dropdown by this below 3 ways(mainly)

### First Way:

please try this way

```
<select ng-model="araba" ng-options="item.name for item in cars" ng-change="Do(this)"></select>
```

**js side**

```
 $scope.Do = function(resp) {
    $scope.val = "current car's val is: " + resp.no;
  };
```

---

### Second Way :

```
<select ng-model="araba" ng-options="item.name for item in cars" ng-change="Do(item)"></select>
```

**js side**

```
     $scope.Do = function(resp) {
        $scope.val = "current car's val is: " + resp.no;
      };
```

---

### Third Way

```
<select ng-model="araba" ng-options="item.name for item in cars" ng-change="Do()"></select>
```

**js side**

```
     $scope.Do = function() {
        $scope.val = "current car's val is: " + $scope.araba.no;
      };
```

Comment: is there also any way (with using first way) to use like ng-change="Do(this.val)" ?? Because i don't want to write any code in my controller scripts.

Comment: okay, that's your wish, you can customize my cod, that's a better sense . good :+1

Comment: but it's not working by using ng-change="Do(this.val) :)

Comment: you can do it bye `ng-change="Do(this.araba.no)"`

Comment: upss sorry.. i mean "ng-change="Do(this.no)""

Answer (score 0):

change the select like,

```
<select ng-model="araba" ng-options="item.name for item in cars" ng-change="Do()"></select>
```

change the `Do()` function as,

```
$scope.Do = function() {
    $scope.val = "current car's val is: " + $scope.araba.no;
};
```

you don't need to pass the selected value to `do()` function. instead you can get the selected value by using `scope` variable `$scope.araba`.

here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fTC6285s7y167szohGWk?p=preview)